# Mobile services azure-not specifying an column value

Tags: c#, sql, azure

```
var items = await App.MobileService.GetTable<Profile>().Where(item => (item.status == status) && 
(item.genre == genre)&&(item.category == category) && (item.location == location) &&
(item.age == age)).ToListAsync();
```

This is my query that I am sending to my azure database to retrieve the results.
Assume the user doesn't specify a location however he satisfies all other requirements. How can I retrieve all the results that are relevant to my query without specifying the location of that specific user and still be able to fetch it. Is there an any type that I can use in the query or a '*' for example.

Answer (score 0):

If I got that correctly, then you can try to Use

```
item.Location.Contains(location)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
&& (string.IsNullOrEmpty(location) || item.location == location) &&
```

Comment: yes thank you I will test in a bit I didn't know there is something called IsNullOrEmpty. Thanks again for the help.